# How can I group by on a field which has NULL values?

Tags: sql, sqlite, null, count, group-by

I have a table with 2 fields

```
 x          y
----       ----
 1         null            
 2          5
 3          5
 4         null
 5         null
 6          10
 7          5
```

And my SQLite query is

```
select y,count(y)
from mytable
group by y
```

And the result is

```
null    0
 5      3
 10     1
```

It is expected to see null  3.
But the output is null  0.
what does it mean?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[From Aggregate Functions in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html)

> The count(X) function returns a count of the number of times that X is not NULL in a group. The count(*) function (with no arguments) returns the total number of rows in the group.

So, the `COUNT` function does not count `NULL` so use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(y)`.

```
SELECT y, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM mytable
GROUP BY y
```

Or you can also use `COUNT(x)` like this one.

```
SELECT y, COUNT(x) AS COUNT
FROM mytable
GROUP BY y
```

#### [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/987f5/6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use isnull in SQL which gives all null values a different identity

Just Run the below query, you will get the desired results

```
Select y,count(isnull(y,-1)) as [Count]
from mytable
group by y
```

Comment: you mean iFnull() ?